# can i search or make query of more than one collection in firestore flutter?if can what is the code

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
                    StreamBuilder(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('Electronics')
                            .where('name', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 'Soundcore')
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (c, s) {
                          var docs = s.data!.docs[0].data().toString();
                          return Text(
                              s.data == null ? 'wait...' : docs.toString());
                        })
```

can i search or make query of more than one collection in firestore flutter?if can what is the code

Comment: Other than collection group queries, no it is not possible.